# How do I get Image of Control on Click in C#?

Tags: c#, image

I want to get exact that Control Image on which I click.

Like If I clicked on Save as option.I should get the save as control Image.

Here is Image Example Which I want to achieve. 
First I clicked on File Menu then Save as.
I want to achieve this

[image: I want to achieve this]

Currently. I am getting the image on clicked base of coordinates of Click.
Like this.I am getting Image on Click base of Click Coordinates.This is not what I want to do.[image: I am getting Image on Click base of Click Coordinates.This is not what I want to do.]

Another Example. I clicked on Stack over flow questions control. I should get this result.
[image: Another Example]

My code.

```
 if (ClientRectangle.Contains(PointToClient(Control.MousePosition)))
        {

           // MessageBox.Show("Width:" + ClientRectangle.Width.ToString() + "--- Height: " + ClientRectangle.Height.ToString() + "---" + "X:" + ClientRectangle.X.ToString() + "--- Y: " + ClientRectangle.Y.ToString());

            Point location = button1.PointToScreen(Point.Empty);

            MessageBox.Show(location.X.ToString()+"---------"+location.Y.ToString()+"---------"+ location+ClientRectangle.Width.ToString()+"---------"+ClientRectangle.Height.ToString());
    //         Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
            int with = ClientRectangle.Width;
            int height = ClientRectangle.Height;
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap((int)with, (int)height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
   // g.CopyFromScreen(ClientRectangle.Left, ClientRectangle.Top, 50,50, bmp.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
    g.CopyFromScreen(location.X, location.Y, 0, 0, new Size(ClientRectangle.Width-30, ClientRectangle.Height-36));
    bmp.Save(@"capture.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

Comment: Sorry, didnt understand a thing?!?

Comment: what you have tried.. Can you please show your code ?

Comment: I want to get Image of that control on which user clicks.e.g I clicked on File Menu , I should get image of File Menu control.

Comment: And.... I believe your second image is wrong or?

Comment: Inside your own app? From anywhere in your app? Are you using WinForms/WPF ?

Comment: From Any where Outside the app or inside the app.

Comment: @RandRandom I am getting 2nd Image. Which is not something I want

Comment: I am using windowsForms

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: use some existing tools to achieve this instead writing code yourself.

Comment: @LeiYang Suggest that tools. secondly I want to add that functionality inside my app which is in C#.

Comment: such as [sharex](https://getsharex.com/)

Comment: sure. and it's open source.

Comment: @LeiYang I am trying sharex.It is also in C#. Maybe it can solve my problem. I will let you know.

Comment: @LeiYang it is not performing the functionality which I want. I want control Image on Click. Like I clicked on stackoverflow Questions icon it should capture the Question Icon control Image.

Comment: Use two clicks to set image size and coordinates, and cut it from screen image based on this data, this is simplest way. Other way how you could do this is image recognition, but it's to huge topic to post it here.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understood from your question, you want to show the image of the menu option on mouse pointer when mouse is pointed/clicked on that particular menu item. If that's so you can do this by changing Cursor:

```
System.Windows.Resources.StreamResourceInfo sri = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("/Images/handClosed.cur", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
Cursor customCursor = new Cursor(sri.Stream);
Mouse.OverrideCursor = customCursor;
```

Here, "/Images/handClosed.cur" is a locally stored image in the project. You can store the images for all the menu item and show them like this based on the menu item.

Edit: This is a WPF Example

---

Check this [Simple Magnifier](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18235/Simple-Magnifier) app. Reference the source and to get the desired effect on mouse click.

Comment: @Not only File Menu. I want to capture image of that particular item on what user click.

Comment: For example. User clicked on stack over flow Questions tab while running my app, I just want to capture Questions tab Image.

Comment: so you want to capture anything the mouse is pointing towards outside of your app as well, and then show the image on mouse pointer, just like what Windows Magnifier does??

Comment: you are damn righ but not what mouse is pointing instead when mouse click is pressed. then I want to capture on what mouse clicked is pressed.

Comment: This not working for me. This app is just magnifying.

Comment: @LeiYang. I just need an Idea. I will write myself

Comment: sharex has all the ideas. say if you have solved your problem, one day somebody else come up with a new question saying 'i need save the image when i mouse over a button, but your example is when clicking the button, that is not i want!' what will you think?